# tensorflow2 how to print tensor value

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I try to print the actual value of the tensor which is loaded from my custom tfds dataset.
I can't figure out how to do it. I am using Tensorflow2 so the session is no longer encouraged.
I tried using .numpy() tf.print. tf.executing.eagerly() but nothing works. It either prints
just the tensor object showing me the shape or in case of .numpy() it throws the error in the title.
I need the value of tensors and I need to bring it back to numpy in order to debugg the code.

This is how I create the dataset:

```
class dt(tfds.core.GeneratorBasedBuilder):
    ''' Dataset builder'''

    # DOuble check
    VERSION = tfds.core.Version('1.0.0')
    RELEASE_NOTES = {
      '1.0.0': 'Initial release.',
    }

    def _info(self) ->tfds.core.DatasetInfo:
        '''Dataset metadata'''

        return tfds.core.DatasetInfo(
            builder=self,
            features=tfds.features.FeaturesDict({
                "id": tf.int64,
                "image": tfds.features.Image(shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS), encoding_format='png'),
                "mask": tfds.features.Image(shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 1), encoding_format='png'),
                "label": tfds.features.ClassLabel(names=CLASSES),
            }),
        supervised_keys=('image', 'mask')
        )

    def _split_generators(self, dl_manager: tfds.download.DownloadManager):
        '''Splitgenerator for train and test splits'''

        path = DATASETS_ROOT
        return {
            "train": self._generate_examples(
                images_path=os.path.join(path, "train/rgb"),
                masks_path=os.path.join(path, "train/masks")
                ),
            "test": self._generate_examples(
                images_path=os.path.join(path, "test/rgb"),
                masks_path=os.path.join(path, "test/masks")
                )
        }

    def _generate_examples(self, images_path, masks_path):
        '''Generator of examples for each split'''
        
        for i, (image, mask) in enumerate(zip(glob.glob(images_path + "/*.png"), glob.glob(masks_path + "/*.png"))):
            yield i, {
                "id": i,
                "image": image,
                "mask": mask,
                "label": CLASSES[3],
            }
```

This is how I try to extract the numpy array

```
def custom_load_X_Y(training=True):

    if training:
        dt, dt_info = tfds.load("dt", split="train", shuffle_files=True, as_supervised=True, with_info=True)

        print(f'EAGERLY {tf.executing_eagerly()}')
        print(f'MOde type {type(dt)}')
        tf.print(f"aaaaa {dt.numpy()} aaaaaa")
```

Console output:

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYysQ.png)

Comment: You seem to have edited out a bit, " it throws the error in the title." There is no error in the title. So you're creating a tfds data set? Can you make a minimal reproducible example? What is "dt" and "dt_info". I suspect you need to do something to fetch the data, otherwise dt.numpy() could be an insane operation.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I debugged it too many times :D dt is the created data set, as per edit.

Comment: Have you looked at their example? https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets You should be calling ds.take to get the numerical data within the dataset.

Comment: Thanks! That should do the trick! I am just confused with this debugging in tensorflow :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print the image dataset by using tfds.show_examples()

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
ds, ds_info = tfds.load('cifar10', split='train', with_info=True)
fig = tfds.show_examples(ds, ds_info)
```

output:

[image]

For more details please refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kiransair/e1e347b61a84403afd99be8c31350b26).Thank You.